# reconciling double-named packages to work with setup.py's install_requires and pip

Tags: python, pip

My package requires openbabel.

openbabel can be installed with `pip install openbabel`

`pip freeze` will then report that `openbabel-python==2.4.1` is installed.

note: if I instead do `pip install openbabel-python`, I will get the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openbabel-python (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for openbabel-python

if I list openbabel-python in my setup.py install_requires:

```
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    install_requires=['openbabel-python>=2.4.0']
)
```

I will get the same error listed above, when pip tries and fails to install openbabel-python.

If I list openbabel instead:

```
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    install_requires=['openbabel>=2.4.0']
)
```

then pip will successfully install openbabel when it is not installed. However, when it *is* installed, it will fail to identify that it has been installed.

> mypackage requires openbabel>=2.4.0, which is not installed.

openbabel is not my package, so I cannot make any changes to it to be more usable. Are there changes I can make to my setup.py to reconcile the two names?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. When installing via `pip install openbabel`, the `openbabel` package gets installed and the `install_requires=['openbabel==2.4.1']` works just fine. You might have some issue with your local setup - what happens if you create a new virtual environment, check that no `openbabel` package is listed when you are listing the packages with `pip list` and then install from scratch with `pip install --no-cache openbabel`?

Comment: yoiu installed openbabel before installing the package that requires it, and when you installed the package with the requirement it did not *reinstall* openbabel because it thought it wasn't installed? I can't reproduce your failure to reproduce, both on ubuntu and on windows...

Comment: No, I mean this: _`openbabel` can be installed with `pip install openbabel` ... `pip freeze` will then report that `openbabel-python==2.4.1` is installed._ This is already not reproducible with Python 3.6 / `pip==19.0.3` / `openbabel==2.4.1`. In a fresh venv, `pip` shows that `openbabel` is installed, no mentions of `openbabel-python`. Looking at the package metadata, I can confirm it is also correct. This means your setup is probably already borked before attempting to install `openbabel`; I listed the steps to check first.

Comment: using python 3.6, virtualenv 15.1.0, pip 19.0.3, with pip list not showing openbabel installed beforehand (just pip 19.0.3, setuptools 40.8.0, and wheel 0.33.1), I run `pip install openbabel --no-cache` and get openbabel-python 2.4.1 when i run `pip list`. same thing on a fresh ubuntu virtual machine (with python 3.7).

Comment: is your openbabel being installed from the wheel file (openbabel-2.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) or from the tar.gz?

Comment: I'm installing from source dist, as I don't use windows and the precompiled wheels exist for windows only.

Comment: However, I see that you're right in what concerns the prebuilt wheels for windows - the wheel metadata indeed shows `openbabel_python` in package name field. This is clearly an error. I would report the issue and in the meanwhile, resort to building from source with `pip install openbabel --no-binary=openbabel`. Can be tricky though, as you'll need the openbabel libs on windows and a C compiler.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use the precompiled wheels from PyPI at all. The excellent Christoph Gohlke's [collection of prebuilt wheels for windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) contains [fat wheels for openbabel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#openbabel) that have the correct metadata.